# How to change distance between NavigationButton an ActionBar title in Nativescript?

Tags: android-actionbar, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to decrease the distance between NavigationButton and ActionBar title in a NativeScript app. How to do that for both iOS and Android?

[image]

Comment: There is no distance between them, they are perfectly one underneath the other. Or is it the ActionBar height that you want to change, to a lower value perhaps? Did you try setting a css `height` property? Did you try placing the `height` attribute on the ActionBar element?

Comment: @pkanev I don't want to change the height or vertical distance. I want to change horizontal distance between hamburger menu icon and "Home" text.

Comment: So change the padding/margin of either/both the button and/or the label.

Comment: @pkanev "Home" text is not in a Label tag. It is the title attribute of the ActionBar. I cannot set its padding or margin. Hamburger menu icon is in NavigationButton and it has no margin or padding. As far as I know, we cannot set negative margin on elements in Nativescript. It seems that I have to set the title text as a Label element.

Comment: @pkanev I have used a label instead of title attribute. Result is the same and I cannot fix it by changing padding and margin because they are already 0.

Comment: I am out of ideas then, sorry ;(

Answer (score 2):

You can Customize it by Using Labels inside the Action Items to place It anywhere on Action Bar - You can style it whatever way you want.

```
<ActionBar>
<ActionItem ios.position="popup" (tap)="capturePhoto($event)" android.position="popup" text="delete">

<Label  class="font-awesome actionItemLabel" text="&#xf03e;" color="white" style="font-size: 26; background-color: transparent; width: 40px; text-align: left;"></Label> 

</ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

Comment: You can increase the distance between NavigationButton and ActionBar with that but cannot decrease it.